# Getting result from multiple Futures of different types

Tags: java, concurrency, future

Let's say I have multiple Futures, like:

```
Future<List<String>> future1
Future<Long> future2
Future<AnotherType> future3
```

And I want to wait for a successful completion of all of them.
How would you recommend doing that?

I've seen some samples but they all imply using Futures that return the same type.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, I assume you tried `future1.get(); future2.get(); future3.get(); ` If so, what didn't meet your requirements? If you have many of these, you could still simply put them into multiple collections of the same type.

Comment: And do you want to collect the results at all?

Comment: I assume using get in sequence is naive and isn't the most optimal thing to do as I should probably get on the slowest and not on the first. Am I missing something? And of course I need the result so eventually I need to get them I just want to get in the most effective way

Comment: You can use CountDownLatch if you know count of your tasks. Isn't it what you are looking for?